# Manipulate certificate in windows 8 application

Tags: javascript, http, https, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

i have app in windows 8 (written using javascript and js api ver. 2.0).
I have simple question if its possible to get certificate from https website and then check its fingerprint ?

i tried httpclient but it simply doesn't have option to retrive certificates ?

Thanks for any directions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,
i managed this,
API expose socket, reference can be found: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.sockets.aspx)

```
var streamSocket = new Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocket();
```

when we create socket we get instance of `StreamSocketInformation` which has `ServerCertificate` property.